# msbuild this application couldn't be started

Tags: windows-8, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

i've got computer with Windows 8 and fresh installation of Visual Studio 13 Express.
I'm working on project which runs on .NET 4.0 Client profile.

Problem is when i try to complile, this error message is shown:

[image: Error Message]

**Solutions:**

[social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/13884c88-f0b5-4f71-8520-eea1ab012957/cant-build-my-project-on-vs-2013-preview-msbuildexe-needs-net-framework-451?forum=msbuild) : This one says:

- try to restart your VS and rebuild - not working
- check MSbuild from promt - not working (Message is shown twice)
- I also checked project configuration *vsproj* and tried to make sample project

Reinstall framework:

- i tried ot reinstall almost everything, framework, sdk.
- when i've installed .NET Framerork v4.5.2 my VS was unnable to start and anoter .NET apps complied before had missing library

I haven't tried to reinstall VS, yet. (*But i dont think if it helps*)

**Edit:** Temporary solution shoud be Visual Studio Express 2012, but it not solves problem.
Reinstalaion of VS didn't help.

Comment: What happens when you install .Net 4.5.1?

Comment: It's in part wit reinstall framework, but not exactly: with .NET 4.5.1, msbuild still fails with that message.

Comment: Come again?  What do you mean `It's in part wit reinstall framework`

Comment: It mean there was pre-installed .NET 4.5.1, after some survey, I tried  to uninstall it and intall it. (first item)

Comment: I've already tried to reinstall Visual Studio -> error message still shown.

With .Net 4.5.2 I've got mysterious error while loading Visual Studio 'The operation could not be completed' and other apps got error 'MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll is missing'